# How can I exit thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

Hi guy I am writing a socket programming in python and using multithreading but I have one problem when I want to exit a program It seem like I can not exit a running thread.

[picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubZQt.png)

```
def create_workers():
for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
    t = threading.Thread(target=work)
    t.daemon = True  # End the Thread
    t.start()



def work():
    while True:

        x = queue.get()
        if x == 1:
            create_socket()
            bind_socket()
            accept_connections()
        if x == 2:
            start_turtle()
            break

        queue.task_done()
```

the function create_workers are  running two thread and targeting function work but I don't really know to terminate it after I break a while loop in function work

Comment: The thread terminates and deletes itself once its target function (`work`) returns, which happens when you `break` out of the loop. Do you want all worker threads to terminate if one of them finishes?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Yes I want all worker thread to terminate and exit a program if either one of them finished

Comment: `t.daemon = True  # End the Thread` doesn't make any sense. Turning on the `daemon` flag doesn't end a thread, and even if it did, why would you try to end a thread immediately *before* you start it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) instance as a flag that you set just before `work` ends, and check if it is set at the start of each iteration of the infinite loop.

If your `work` function is more complicated, with multiple `return` statements, you could chuck the `event.set()` call into the `finally` block of a `try` statement.

`threading.Event` is thread-safe.

As pointed out by *user2357112 supports Monica*, making the threads daemonic doesn't make sense, so I've removed that line.

```py
def create_workers():
    event = threading.Event()
    for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(event,))
        t.start()

def work(event):
    while True:
        if event.is_set():
            return
        
        x = queue.get()
        if x == 1:
            create_socket()
            bind_socket()
            accept_connections()
        if x == 2:
            start_turtle()
            break
        
        queue.task_done()
    
    event.set()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `python-worker` ([link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/))

```
from worker import abort_all_thread

## your running code

abort_all_thread() # this will kill any active threads
```